# partial display of button in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have created an AlertDialog with OK button. But it is only displaying the button partially.

[screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/29lfcjc.png)

### I use following code

```
private void showErrorDialog(String msg) {
            final int 
    //Log.i(tag, "showAlert with message: " + msg);
    final AlertDialog.Builder errDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    errDialog.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", listener);

    TextView txtView = new TextView(context);
    txtView.setSingleLine(false);
    txtView.setText(msg);

    errDialog.setView(txtView);

    //Log.i(tag, "dialog created");
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.i(tag, "showing dialog ..............");
            MyUIClass.errorDialog = errDialog.create();
            context.showDialog(MyUIClass.ERROR_DIALOG_ID/* , null */);
        }
    });
    //Log.i(tag, "show()");
}
```

---

What could be the issue?

thanks

Comment: Why have you used `runOnUiThread` method to show dialog?

Comment: @PareshMayani because this code is out of UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to Use Dialog in Case when you want Customize View to Show TextView and Button Below It.

Check Reference Link for Creating Dialog you want . http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: well, couldn't find why its happening when I use setPositiveButton("Ok", listener) to add button to dialog. I created my own layout with buttons and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

in your function use below code::

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle(null);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setMessage(msg);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Do nothing
            }
        });
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you havent decleared the size of dialog check this

```
 private void showErrorDialog(String msg) {
               // final int 
        //Log.i(tag, "showAlert with message: " + msg);
        final AlertDialog.Builder errDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       // errDialog.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        errDialog.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", listener);


        TextView txtView = new TextView(context);
        txtView.setSingleLine(false);
        txtView.setText(msg);
       errDialog.addView(txtView , new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

       //errDialog.setView(txtView);

        //Log.i(tag, "dialog created");
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.i(tag, "showing dialog ..............");
            MyUIClass.errorDialog = errDialog.create();
            context.showDialog(MyUIClass.ERROR_DIALOG_ID/* , null */);
        }
    });
    //Log.i(tag, "show()");
```

}

Comment: Vipin, I do not see setLayoutParams() method in AlertDialog.Builder class.

Comment: oh check my edited code and refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html